# Contingency table error

Tags: r, contingency, r-commander

I'm tryin to make a contingency table on R using the Melanoma data set from MASS package using Rcmdr.

```
local({
    .Table <- xtabs(~sex+status+ulcer, data=Melanoma)
     cat("\nFrequency table:\n")
     print(.Table)
})
```

Every time i try to make a contingency table (also with other data sets) R tells me that the "numb" agument is invalid and it doesn't have a predefined value.

Comment: Works okay in R (after `library(MASS)`) - so seems a Rcmdr issue.

Comment: It also works fine for me.

Comment: should I update rcmdr?

Comment: @GiuseppeMinardi ; possibly. I just installed Rcmdr v2.4.1, using R3.4.2. When I started Rcmdr from the terminal, your code ran without error.

Comment: I uploaded all the packages and it doesn't work

Comment: I mean i have R 3.4.2 and Rcmdr v2.4.1 and it still gives me an error

Comment: I can't reproduce, but maybe someone else can. Can you add the results of `sessionInfo()` to your question please, and mention your workflow - using rstudio, conda etc